# Need both isset and !='

Tags: php, if-statement, isset

I need both `isset` and `!=''` in a condition, if I dont use `isset` it gives warning and I need `!=''` for else condition. So I need to use both

below code works well but dont return else, but when I change `isset($array['1']['name']` to `($array['1']['name'] !=''` then it return else condition.

```
if(isset($array['1']['name'] )) { 
    $this->output('<li class="name">',$array['1']['name'],'</li>'); 
}
else{ 
    $this->output('<li class="name">',$other,'</li>'); 
}
```

Comment: are you sure that `'1'` is a string?

Comment: yes, is there anything wrong?? how to change that??

Comment: If this is deliberate, using string numeric values for array keys seems like a strange idea. To not use a string, simply put $array[1]['name']

Comment: I mean, that that array is actually string-indexed -- if it isn't, you're doing an implicit cast to integer, where it wouldn't be needed. EDIT: What he said ;P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Combine `isset()` with [`empty()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) using the `&&`operator

```
if(isset($array['1']['name']) && !empty($array['1']['name'])) {
```

Comment: You can't test a value if it doesn't exist, this will result in a warning.

Comment: `empty()` does not trigger undefined var notice, so you can just stick to it. Although checking if `$array` and `$array[1]` exist is still needed.

Comment: @Jean-Georges I don't remember the proper term for it, but if the left side of an `&&` is `false` it doesn't bother evaluating the right side.

Comment: @Sammitch That is called a 'conditional and'